# Django (v2+) and Django REST Framework: what to do with "path" interferes?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django REST Framework... but am figuring it out via the tutorials, quick start, internet and fiddling. However, I did not find a clear solution to the following problem.

Suppose one wishes to write an api that requires an integer.

Using Django's `path` in the url patterns one might try:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('my_api/<int:integer_argument>', views.my_api, name='my_api'),
    ...
]
```

and in their view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_api(request, integer_argument):
     # do stuff
     return JsonResponse({'int': integer_argument})
```

Note: here I use JsonResponse just to keep this simple, but most likely that/those argument(s) go into a class/model and into serializer to be returned by `Response(serializer.data)`.

So now if they were to test an application which calls this api (in development mode) `http://localhost:8000/my_api/1` they should get `{'int':1}`.

However, if they were to call `http://localhost:8000/my_api/e` they get the either the debug page or `Bad Request (400)` as ***html***.

Lets assume that the person making the api did have proper error handling in place for to validate the arguments (in this case that `integer_argument` is an integer).

Now `path` is getting in the way, whereas for a django website this might be the desired result.

What is the RESTful and django REST framework endorsed way to handle this situation?

The `path` convert (e.g. `<int:arg_name>`) makes the url conf readable and thus is a nice feature to have.

Should I just move the types to type annotations in the function based view? and use generic slugs?

Note: in this case I want every request to `my_api/<something>` to return a uniform response (error or otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks clarity. You state:

> Lets assume that the person making the api did have proper error handling in place for to validate the arguments (in this case that integer_argument is an integer).

Yeah that would be Django handling things.... Which is why you get the debug page \ Bad Request because it doesn't match.

In your API you're defining endpoints which match that format - precisely. If a uri doesn't match then that's expected behavior you shouldn't be doing any wizardry here because that just doesn't make sense.

If you want to use type annotations sure - mypy is useful and other devs may find it useful as well.

Now for the next bit:

> Note: in this case I want every request to my_api/ to return a uniform response (error or otherwise).

So.... add an endpoint which acts as a catch all to return that uniform response when the other path \ regular expression paths fail to find a match. I think you're overcomplicating this.

Comment: most likely I am overthinking this, however I believe you misinterpret  the first quote. Rather than just having default django error handling due to the path converters, I meant django rest framework error handling e.g. `serializer.ValidationError` and the like